# How to stop overflow behaviour while using slide-in popups

Tags: css, popup, overflow

So I use this code to prevent my website from scrolling horizontally (especially for mobile).

```css
html, body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

While this code is in use my popups with side (left/right) slide-in entrance animation appear below all the content on my website (I need to scroll all the way down below the content to see them). How do I properly stop overflow behaviour and make my popups work?

Answer (score 0):

You also can add `max-width:100vw` in addition to  `overflow-y:hidden`
to the body to be safe :)